# vary a constructor injected string parameter with Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

My goal is to vary a string parameter:

```
Container
 .RegisterInstance<string>("us", @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_us.xml")
 .RegisterInstance<string>("intl", @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_intl.xml");

driver = Container.Resolve<LoaderDriver>(args[1]); // "us" or "intl"
```

Which results in:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "QuickBooksService.LoaderDriver", name = "intl".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving QuickBooksService.LoaderDriver,intl
  Resolving parameter "reader" of constructor QuickBooksService.LoaderDriver(QuickBooksService.LoaderInputReader reader, QuickBooksService.ILoader[] loaders)
    Resolving QuickBooksService.LoaderInputReader,(none)
    Resolving parameter "inputFile" of constructor QuickBooksService.LoaderInputReader(System.String inputFile, AccountingBackupWeb.Models.AccountingBackup.Company company, Qu
ickBooksService.eTargets targets)
      Resolving System.String,(none)
```

This is obviously wrong but its the only way I could get it to work:

```
if (args[1] == "us")
    Container
        .RegisterType<LoaderInputReader>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_us.xml",
                new ResolvedParameter<Company>(),
                new ResolvedParameter<eTargets>()
            )
        )
    ;
else if (args[1] == "intl")
    Container
        .RegisterType<LoaderInputReader>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_intl.xml",
                new ResolvedParameter<Company>(),
                new ResolvedParameter<eTargets>()
            )
        )
    ;
else
    throw new Exception("invalid company");

driver = Container.Resolve<LoaderDriver>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
container
    .RegisterType<LoaderInputReader>(
        "us",
        new InjectionConstructor(
            @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_us.xml",
            new ResolvedParameter<Company>(),
            new ResolvedParameter<eTargets>()));
container
    .RegisterType<LoaderInputReader>(
        "intl",
        new InjectionConstructor(
            @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_intl.xml",
            new ResolvedParameter<Company>(),
            new ResolvedParameter<eTargets>()));
```

This names each registration of `LoaderInputReader`. Now you can resolve like this:

```
var us = container.Resolve<LoaderInputReader>("us");
var intl = container.Resolve<LoaderInputReader>("intl");
```

Comment: You can simplify this a little, by saying: container.RegisterType<LoaderInputReader>("us", new InjectionConstructor(string, typeof(Company), typeof(eTargets)); You only need to explicitly use ResolvedParameter if you're resolving a named dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change

```
driver = Container.Resolve<LoaderDriver>(args[1]); // "us" or "intl"
```

with

```
driver = Container.Resolve<LoaderDriver>(Container.Resolve<string>(args[1]))
```

This takes advantage of the [Resolve overload that takes a name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff662091%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx), where in your case the name comes from your argument.